# Animating another viewcontroller storyboard scene programatically

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am working through a tutorial that is demonstrating a facebook/path left hand nav

http://hsapkota.com.au/index.php/blog/ios-iphone-ipad/28-tutorial-creating-gmail-facebook-like-menu-navigation-in-ios

Everything is working as expected, however I wanted to add a close navigation button in the navigation table, but I can't seem to fire the same method or access the storyboard scene from the navigation class

this is an example of one way I was trying to perform the task

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSString * storyboardName = @"MainStoryboard_iPhone";
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];

UINavigationController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"main"];



[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear

                 animations:^{

                     CGAffineTransform trans = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(200.0, 0.0);


                     vc.view.transform= trans;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){

                 }
 ];

}
```

'main' is the storyboardID I that is I would like to animate, however on performing an NSLog on 'vc.navigationController' I get a NULL return  - although logging 'vc' returns the class name associated with the correct storyboard scene

Any help would be appreciated I just can't get my head around it!

-edit
I thought I was able to edit the 'main view' calling superview in my transform
    self.view.superview.transform= trans

however this animates both viewcontrollers and also renders 'main view' useless as non of the tap gestures respond in this view now...

Any further thoughts?

Comment: You shouldn't be instantiation a new controller, you should be interacting with the existing one (the presenting view controller perhaps).

Comment: Thanks! any ideas how would I go about doing that? if I create instance of the class responsible for the main scene any attempts to access the properties of self.navigationController (even a method set up to return that ) show up as null when instantiated from the nav class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay after a lot of faffing about I managed to get something to work

I needed to contact the appdelegate in order to access the other viewcontroller in context

my code is now

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

AppDelegate* appDel = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
MainView *mv = (MainView *)appDelegate.window.rootViewController;


[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear

                 animations:^{

                     CGAffineTransform trans = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-0.0, 0.0);

                    mv.view.transform= trans;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){


                 }
 ];
```

}